# Stack around variables corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

So I was doing a little test doing our programming classes, and being fairly new to coding, I made a mistake somewhere in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const int m = 4;                            
    int n = 3, p = 46, i;                       
    int X[m];                                   
    int q[m];                           

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)                     
        q[i] = p;                               
    q[i+1] = p - q[i] / n;
    if (q[i] = 0)
    {
        X[i] = n;
    }
    else{ X[i] = q[i] / pow(n, m - i); }
    cout << "Rezultatai: " << X << endl;
}
```

It keeps showing errors that variables `X` and `q` are corrupted and I have no idea where I went wrong.

Comment: `if (q[i] = 0)` <-- `q[i] == 0`, also `X[i]`, `q[i+1]`, `q[i]` after the loop will all be out of bounds. Oh and `void main` should be `int main`.

Comment: give brackets for the `for loop` because it's unclear which part is inside loop. i personally feel you have made mistake in typing the program properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you've read outside the bounds of your array. You declare `q` as an array with 4 elements, beginning at index 0 and ending at index 3.

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    q[i] = p;
```

After this for loop, `i` will have the value of `m` (4), making it not a valid subscript. Every time you use `i` after this as a subscript operator (like `q[i]`), you're in the realm of undefined behavior. It's what is causing the corruption. I don't know what you wanted to do, but you need to make sure that `0 <= i && i < m`.

Some other things:

```
if (q[i] = 0)
```

Aside from the fact that `i` is still not within the bounds of `q`, you wanted `==` here. The `==` operator compares equality, and evaluates to `true` or `false` like how you would expect. The `=` operator assigns the right argument to the left one. It also evaluates to a reference to the left argument, and since anything "not zero" is `true` and `zero` is false, this will compile and end up being `false`.

```
void main()
```

This should be `int main()`.